# Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR SpringBoot Angular : OneToMany Problem

Tags: angularjs, angular, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

evrey time i try to load List RDV i hade this problem :

****Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.angular.springboot.model.Rv["client"]->com.angular.springboot.model.Client$HibernateProxy$3lai3IqI["hibernateLazyInitializer"])]**

**o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR****

but whene i remove the **OneToMany** it's work !!

this is my Client class :

```
public class Client implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long        id;
private String      name;
private String      prenom;

@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Rv>    lrdvs;

@JsonIgnore
public List<Rv> getLrdvs() {
    return lrdvs;
}

@JsonIgnore
public void setLrdvs(List<Rv> lrdvs) {
    this.lrdvs = lrdvs;
}
```

}

this is Medecin class:

```
 @Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "medecins")
public class Medecin implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long        id;
private String      nom;
private String      prenom;
private String      specialite;
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "medecin", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Rv>    lrdvs;

@JsonIgnore
public List<Rv> getLrdvs() {
    return lrdvs;
}

@JsonIgnore
public void setLrdvs(List<Rv> lrdvs) {
    this.lrdvs = lrdvs;
}
```

}

this is my RDV class

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Rv {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long        id;
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate   jour;

@JoinColumn(name = "ID_Client")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private Client      client;

@JoinColumn(name = "ID_Medecin")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private Medecin     medecin;

public Rv() {
    client = new Client();
    medecin = new Medecin();
}
```

}

any one plz know how to solve it. thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your application properties

```
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
```

Comment: Check out https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonmappingexception